# Making text disappear when not hovering over it

Tags: html, css

I am trying to recreate an effect I saw on ["TheButton" subreddit](http://reddit.com/r/thebutton).  You can see that next to most usernames there is a colored dot that when hovered over expands and reveals some underlying text.

Using their CSS as a starting point, I can recreate this effect but my issue is that the underlying text I have does not collapse, so I never achieve a "dot" shape while the user is not hovering.

Here's my CSS:

```
* {
    font: normal x-small verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
}
.flair {
    min-width: 12px;
    max-width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 10px !important;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
    transition-delay: 1s;
    position: relative;
}
.flair:hover {
    max-width: 500px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
.flair-no-press {
    background:#888;
    color:#888;
}
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<span class="flair flair-no-press" title="non presser">non presser</span>
```

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4za9stj/) showing what this looks like.  Once again my intended effect is simply making the dot collapse entirely when not being hovered over like they have.

What am I missing here?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t4za9stj/1/ - just needed to add `display: inline-block` to .flair

Comment: Thank you very much!  Why does adding the `display: inline-block;` solve the problem?

Comment: You can't assign a width to an inline element, so it needs to be a block or inline-block element.